# How to include anonymous page views when using GA4 UI / Data Studio Connector and Cookiebot?

Tags: google-analytics

We are using UA and GA4 via Google Tag Manager and we have Cookiebot managing user's consent. We are also having GA4 BigQuery output enabled.
We would like to count anonymous page views when users didn't consent to cookies.

i.e. the expectation is that we can count page views and potentially other events, but it wouldn't be connected to a user's session or contain personal identifiable information.
(the assumption is that this should be GDPR compliant)

However, using specific page URLs, I tried to test the behaviour and I observed that no event was recorded before accepting cookies.

In our BigQuery data, we can also see see some events that do not have a `ga4_session_id`.
(The assumption was that those people didn't consent to cookies, but this might be wrong)

When comparing the numbers with the GA4 UI or Data Studio Connector, it appears that the events without a session id are not included in the GA4 UI / Connector page view numbers.
i.e. even if BigQuery data without session id were for people not accepting cookies, those wouldn't be counted by the GA4 UI or Data Studio Connector.

How can I can I count anonymous page views using the GA4 UI and Google Data Studio Connector?

(I've posted the same question to Analytics Help forum but didn't get a response)